# SQL Case When not labeling null

Tags: mysql, sql, null

I'm trying to do this [Leet Code Problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/second-highest-salary/):

Write a SQL query to get the second highest salary from the Employee table.

```
+----+--------+
| Id | Salary |
+----+--------+
| 1  | 100    |
| 2  | 200    |
| 3  | 300    |
+----+--------+
```

For example, given the above Employee table, the query should return 200 as the second highest salary. If there is no second highest salary, then the query should return null.

```
+---------------------+
| SecondHighestSalary |
+---------------------+
| 200                 |
+---------------------+
```

I'm trying to give this solution:

```
SELECT 
      CASE WHEN Salary = '' 
         THEN NULL 
         ELSE Salary END SecondHighestSalary 
   FROM 
      Employee 
   ORDER BY 
      SecondHighestSalary 
   LIMIT 1,1;
```

When there is a second salary, it works fine and returns the output. However, when there is no second salary and there's only one salary only an empty string is returned. I'm trying to return `NULL`, however, it doesn't return `NULL` like what I wrote in my query. How can I fix this?

Comment: What is the datatype of `Salary` and why are you comparing it to an empty-string if it's actually a numeric type?

Comment: Your query doesn't work if two employees both have the same highest salary, btw (unless that's intentional?).

Comment: @Dai datatype of salary is numeric, but if the value returned is empty, what should I compare it to?

Comment: in SQL (that's **all** SQL databases: MySQL, MS SQL Server, Postgres, even MS Access) there is no such thing as an "empty number" (whereas text fields **can** be empty, or rather: zero-length). All "empty" numeric values are actually `NULL`, and you **must** use `IS NULL` (not `= NULL`) to test for them (or use `COALESCE` where applicable). Your current query with `Salary = ''` works in MySQL because MySQL is more forgiving (and less standards-compliant) than other databases. Your query as-is will either fail with a number/string/type error or return unexpected results.

Comment: @Dai Even when I use `IS NULL` instead, it still returns an empty string as the result

Comment: First thing the query you have shown doesn't deliver the second highest salary rather second lowest one. Second where do you expect the case expression `case salary=''`  to be match. The select expression executes before order by and limit so no record with empty string will match in first place and finally as others said you should not check the null like how you did.

Comment: @user2896120 It does not return an "empty string" - it **will** return `NULL` too - it's just that some layer between the MySQL network client and the LeetCode website is converting it to a string. If you run the query directly against a real MySQL database using MySQL Workbench or in a PHP script you'll see it returns `NULL` and not an empty-string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `CASE` expression is testing the salary in each row of the table, not the one selected by the `LIMIT` clause. Ordering is done *after* generating the values in the `SELECT` list, since you can order by those calculated values.

Since none of the salaries are empty strings, the condition in your `CASE` will never be true, so it always returns the `Salary` value. As a result, your query is equivalent to

```
SELECT Salary AS SecondHighestSalary
FROM Employee
ORDER BY SecondHighestSalary
LIMIT 1, 1
```

Other things:

1. You need to use `DESC` to get the highest salary at the beginning. So even if your method worked, it would find the second *lowest* salary.
2. Your method doesn't handle the case where multiple employees are tied for the highest salary. `LIMIT 1, 1` will return the second row, which will be one of the tied employees.

You can solve the second problem using a subquery that removes duplicates:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Salary
FROM Employee
```

So a final query could be:

```
SELECT IF(COUNT(*) > 0, MAX(Salary), NULL) AS SecondHighestSalary
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT Salary
    FROM Employee
    ORDER BY Salary DESC
    LIMIT 1, 1
) AS x
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this solution, where if there have no second highest salary will return NULL. Otherwise will return second highest salary

```
SELECT 
   IFNULL(MIN(Salary) , 'NULL') as SecondHighestSalary
FROM
    Employee
WHERE salary > (SELECT MIN(salary)
                 FROM Employee)
```

Or if you want DB default null then just remove IFNULL condition

```
SELECT 
   MIN(Salary) as SecondHighestSalary
FROM
    Employee
WHERE salary > (SELECT MIN(salary)
                 FROM Employee)
```

Answer (score 0):

E.g.

```
 select max(salary) salary 
   from employee 
 where salary not in 
 (select max(salary) from employee)
```

Comment: I know that is one way of doing it, but I want to understand my other way isn't working

Comment: Your other way doesn't tackle the problem. If all salaries were 200, it wouldn't even occur to you to try that solution

Comment: I understand, but I want to understand how to do my query that way if I ever use `case` I'll understand when to give defaults to values that don't exist

Comment: How would you change your query to account for the third largest salary or fourth largest salary?

Comment: You can't. The limitation is imposed by the 'null' requirement. We'd have to approach it in a different way, beyond the scope of this question. CASE would be unlikely to form part of the solution however